# How do I create and draw an array of images on a canvas using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying the following code to allow me to create an image, allow custom values attached to it and draw in on an HTML canvas. It doesn't seem to be working though.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
function CreateObject(objectImage){
    lastIndex++;
    PlanObjects[lastIndex] = new PlanObject(lastIndex,currentSlide,24,24,24,24,objectImage);
    context.drawImage(PlanObjects[lastIndex].img,PlanObjects[lastIndex].posX,PlanObjects[lastIndex].posY);
}

var PlanObjects = [];
var lastIndex = -1;
var currentSlide = 0;

function PlanObject(id, slide, width, height, posX, posY, img){
    this.id = id;
    this.slide = slide;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.img = new Image(img);
}

CreateObject("imgs/icons_star.png");
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mainCanvasDiv"><canvas width="800" height="600" id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
```

I expect to create the object, store it in the array of PlanObjects (with it's customer values) and draw it onto the canvas but it doesn't seem to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The input parameters for the image constructor are width and height. And you must separately set the source:

```
var myImage = new Image(100, 200);
myImage.src = 'picture.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(myImage);
```

[ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image ]

2) Loading an image is asynchronous, so you need to handle the `load` event:

```
PlanObjects[lastIndex].img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  context.drawImage(PlanObjects[lastIndex].img, PlanObjects[lastIndex].posX, PlanObjects[lastIndex].posY)
});
```

[ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load ]

[ https://jsfiddle.net/bvupyroc/ ]

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the new Image line to fix the problem

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
function CreateObject(objectImage){
    lastIndex++;
    PlanObjects[lastIndex] = new PlanObject(lastIndex,currentSlide,24,24,24,24,objectImage);
    context.drawImage(PlanObjects[lastIndex].img,PlanObjects[lastIndex].posX,PlanObjects[lastIndex].posY);
}

var PlanObjects = [];
var lastIndex = -1;
var currentSlide = 0;

function PlanObject(id, slide, width, height, posX, posY, img){
    this.id = id;
    this.slide = slide;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = img;
}

CreateObject("./imgs/icons_star.png");
```